# Blank select options on Chrome / Chromium & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an Acer Aspire 4750G laptop.  Recently I've started having a problem with HTML SELECT option lists when using Chrome or Chromium.

Normally everything works fine, then the select options on web pages will start showing as blank.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The problem occurs erratically and happens with both Chrome and Chromium, but not with Firefox.  Once it happens I have to close all Chrome/Chromium sessions to get rid of it.

Once it occurs it happens on all sites but only seems to affect  options.  It's not a CSS error because the above sample was created with the most basic code possible:

```
<body>  
<table>  
    <tr>
        <td>Test Select:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="test">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="4">Option 4</option>
                <option value="5">Option 5</option>
                <option value="6">Option 6</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

If I look at the page source in the browser it looks fine, and I can select the options by cursoring up and down, but they don't display and I can't select with a mouse click.

Can anyone suggest why this may be happening?  I've hunted Google but can't find a single reference to this problem.  Would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks
Don

Comment: Hello! I have the same problem - did you perhaps find a solution for this?

Comment: @daxur - No solution yet although it seems to be a graphics driver problem.  I am using an Acer Aspire 4750G with the dubious Optimus chip set.  Have discovered that the problem occurs in browser windows displayed on an external HDMI monitor but if I drag that browser window to the internal laptop display it is fine.  Dragging it back to the external display fails again.

I'm running the default Nouveau drivers -- last time I tried installing the NVidia drivers I lost the system completely and had to reinstall to get it back so a bit paranoid about doing that again.

Comment: some co workers have the same problem. I think that not all of them have the same cpu/gpu. i know that not all of them have a dedicated gpu - the most have just an an 4th generation intel with an an Intel HD 4400 GPU. actually noone has the problem so i can't test if it works on the notebook monitor.

Comment: Same thing here, trying to find a solution

Comment: Same here. @DonDunlop tip works for me too : issue occurs only on external monitor (wired through VGA cable though, not hdmi). On laptop display options get displayed as expected.

Comment: I have this on Elementary 0.4.1 too. That's based on Ubuntu 16.04. And none of the answers here works for me, not even restarting Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

You have to turn off the hardware acceleration!

Check this out for the detailed solution -- I don't feel like copy pasting the whole thing and stealing someone else's answer!

http://www.solveyourtech.com/turn-hardware-acceleration-google-chrome/

The summary is that you need to go to 'settings' then 'advanced settings' in Chrome, then uncheck the hardware acceleration box.

Comment: Sorry...  been off for a while and this is my first chance to test again.  

The problem I described occurred this morning so I turned off the hardware acceleration  as per (excellent) instruction, and the problem immediately went away.  However turning off hardware acceleration requires a restart of Chrome which usually fixes the problem by itself, so hard to tell whether this did it or not.

I'll run it like this for a couple of weeks to make sure, but if the problem doesn't recur in that time then this would appear to do it.

Comment: this worked for me. I'm on Fedora 21 and Chrome 46

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem for me.  Turning hardware acceleration off requires a Chrome restart and that temporarily fixed the problem, but it did recur.

Having said that I have found a workable workaround.  Restarting Chrome gets rid of the problem temporarily.  Using chrome://restart will do this without losing content in your tabs.  I just created an item on my bookmark bar called 'Reset' and pointed it to chrome://restart.  When the problem occurs I click that, Chrome restarts and voila. Not very elegant but better than rebooting.

Comment: hehe, but [Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.amazon.com/The-Pragmatic-Programmer-Journeyman-Master/dp/020161622X) states: “select” Isn’t Broken
It is rare to find a bug in the OS or the compiler, or even a third-party product or library. The bug is most likely in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to latest grapgics stack.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

> Trusty
>
> The 14.04.2 and newer point release will ship with an updated kernel
>   and X stack by default. If you have installed with older media you can
>   use the following to install the newer kernel from 15.04 (Vivid):
>
> DESKTOP

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

> MULTIARCH DESKTOP
>
> If you run a multiarch desktop (for example, i386 and amd64 on amd64,
>   for gaming or Wine), you may find you need a slightly more involved
>   command, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386
```

Comment: Thanks Yurii...  I did try this and it seemed better at first but unfortunately the problem recurred.  I do have a nice new kernel now, though.  :-)  As a workaround setting chrome://restart as a bookmark fixes the problem when it comes up.   Ok for now.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: None of these fixes work in 18.04.x ...