# Chrome's select box broken when I'm with two displays Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, display

If I plug a second display to my Ubuntu 14.04, in one of them all the select box in pages open in Google Chrome appear like this:
[First display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO7MH.png)

The same page opened in the other display appears correctly: [Second display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggj1d.png)

Someone could help me with this?

Comment: We had a colleague, which was wondering doing something wrong on his code. After finding your question couldn't even believe this to be true, but it funnily turned out to be exactly the same behavior on his machine!! Just incredible :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blank select options on Chrome / Chromium & Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641098/blank-select-options-on-chrome-chromium-ubuntu-14-04)